# during a windows defender scan can i play games still?

Tags: windows

my son wishes to play a new game but I have started a comprehensive scan on windows defender. can he safely still play his game?

Comment: Does your question refer to performing a scan _while_ your son is playing? Can you edit the question so that it becomes more clear what you are actually asking for?

Comment: Not really an Information Security question as such. May be better received on SuperUser?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good idea *not* to run other programs during an anti-malware scan, but it will not cause any damage to the system if you do. However, if the game was infected, it could be harder for Defender to detect.

Answer (score 0):

A anti-virus scan is a disk intensive operation that will most likely slow down your computer until it's completion.

Technically you can perform other tasks while it's running, but you will most likely perceive a quite frustrating slowness in your computer, far from ideal to run games.

The main reason it shouldn't interfere with the scan is because the live protection should prevent you from loading any files with viruses to begin with, so in theory no files the anti-virus scan could possibly want to quarantine should be locked in use.

However this concurrency between the game and the anti-virus scan will also cause the scan to take much longer to complete.